# Is there a Python method to calculate moving RMS of a signal? How to calculate the moving RMS using the discrete signal formula?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, moving-average

I'm trying to calculate a moving RMS of an acceleration signal.

One of the answers in the [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42059/difference-between-rms-and-a-moving-rms), shows the formula for calculating moving RMS for discrete signal.

The formula they suggest:

[image]

I have a few questions on this formula. Since $i$ would be, for most part of the summation, less than $N$(no of samples), therefore k would be negative and the negative index does not make sense to me. That's why I'm having trouble understanding this formula.

Also, is there a python method to find moving RMS of a signal like MATLAB has `dsp.MovingRMS`?

Comment: you're misinterpreting what $N$ is in that formula.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The referenced answer discussing the equation uses a following equation $T = Nd\tau$ where they say $d\tau $ is the sampling time. So my understanding is that if $T$ being the total measurement time, wouldn't that mean $N$ would be the number of samples? I'm just trying to understand this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few solutions, you can recognize that you have the square root of the rolling mean of the squared magnitude of the signal. Using pandas [rolling mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html?highlight=rolling#pandas-core-window-rolling-rolling-mean) this could be written as follows.

```py
import pandas as pd;

def rolling_rms(x, N):
  return (pd.DataFrame(abs(x)**2).rolling(N).mean()) **0.5
```

Each entry in the result contains the RMS of `N` contiguous samples, where `i < N` the result is filled with `nan`.

If you care more for efficiency you can do something like this

```py
import numpy as np;
def rolling_rms(x, N):
    xc = np.cumsum(abs(x)**2);
    return np.sqrt((xc[N:] - xc[:-N]) / N)
```

this particular implementation skips the first valid entry, so if you want it, you can insert a zero at the beginning of `x`.

Comment: you are squaring the values so there is no need of abs(x), just x**2

Comment: @Spas, what about `(1+1j)**2` ?